# Define types of arguments in Ctypes and passing arguments to C DLL

Tags: python, c, dll, arguments, ctypes

I'm new to Python, Ctypes and have little knowledge on C.
I defined a function in MATLAB. Here is the function and its arguments:

```
function Out = Read_clipboard (im, num1,num2,num3,num4)
```

im: array (500 x 500 x 3) unit8 (this is an image)

num1: double

num2: double

num3: double

num4: double

Out: (1 x 2000) double (something like: [1 2 3 4 5 ..... 2000] in matlab)
.
.

I used MATLAB Coder and successfully turned my function into MEX which works fine.

I also used MATLAB Coder and converted my function into C DLL. I successfully compiled MATLAB Code to CDLL using "minGW Compiler" which I have already installed on my WIN7-64.

Now I want to use the generated C DLL inside Python IDE to achieve faster runs comparing to MATLAB runs. I use Ctypes and my Python code is:

```
from ctypes import windll 
from ctypes import *
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('b0.jpg',1)
mylib = windll["Read_clipboard.dll"]
my_func=getattr(mylib,'Read_clipboard')
my_func.restype = ????
my_func.argtypes=[???,c_double,c_double,c_double,c_double]
output = my_func(im,100,2000,30/255,30))
```

Now I don't know how to define types of input and output arguments so that the function in C DLL would work in python. MATLAB Coder has also generated C codes for my function. "function declarations" in header file (.h extension) is as below:

```
  /* Function Declarations */
extern void Read_clipboard(const unsigned char im[750000], double
  num1, double num2, double num3, double num4,
  emxArray_real_T *Out);

#endif
```

How should I define types of input and output in python and pass them to the DLL?

Many thanks

Comment: C++ and C are not the same language. Ctypes is to link C code. But I think MATLAB Coder produces C code, so you should be fine. You just need to [edit] your question to use the C tag and not confuse it with C++.

Comment: Dear Cris many thanks for your response. When generating DLL in MATLAB Coder there are options for both C and C++. I chose C++ because I thought it would be faster than C but I'm not sure. I also once generated C code and C DLL. one difference was names of functions inside each DLL type. In C DLL functions had their original names and in C++ DLL names are changed with some random characters added to the original names. So you say that there is a chance that Ctypes in python only works with C DLL types and not with C++ DLLs. I have to Google check it. Any much help is appreciated.

Comment: Indeed. C++ mangles names of functions (so that they can be overloaded). This mangling is unique to C++ (and different on different platforms and compilers), and therefore makes it impossible for other languages to link to C++ libraries (unless those languages have very specific support for C++). On the other hand, C is the default and standard for DLLs, any language that allows linking to a DLL can link to a C DLL.

Comment: If you have a header file (.h extension) that comes with your DLL, it will tell you the types of the function arguments.

Comment: Useful Points. Fortunately I have already generated the C version of my DLL successfully. I edit my question and use C tag instead of C++.  Thanks.

Comment: I just added .h file of C DLL to my question. Arguments are clearly declared in the header file. Now the question is that how should I define my arguments in Python so that the C DLL would work. 
I know Ctypes library has some features for defining types of arguments but had no success after trying some of them. One of my input arguments is an image with a 3Dimensional array, and that is the main problem I believe.